# Execute immediate throws error when using record attribute in dynamic statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am executing the following snippet of code

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  TYPE emp_rec_type IS record (emp_id NUMBER,salary NUMBER);
  emp_rec emp_rec_type;

  l_out number;
  l_statement varchar2(1000);

BEGIN
    emp_rec.emp_id := 1;
    emp_rec.salary := 1000;

    SELECT emp_rec.salary INTO l_out FROM dual WHERE 1=1;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_out);

    l_statement := 'select emp_rec.salary from dual where 1=1';
    execute immediate l_statement into l_out;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_out);
END;
```

I am getting the below output

```
  Error report:
       ORA-00904: "EMP_REC"."SALARY": invalid identifier
       ORA-06512: at line 23
       00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
       *Cause:    
         *Action:

       1000
```

I am expecting the output to be

```
1000
1000
```

Why is it that the dynamic statement execution insists on emp_rec.salary being an invalid identifer while the Select into statement works fine? 
Is there something else I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement is running in a completely different scope to the rest of your PL/SQL code - you can't reference PL/SQL variables directly.

If you want to use the contents of `emp_rec.salary` in the dynamic statement, you should bind in the value like so:

```
l_statement := 'SELECT :1 FROM dual WHERE 1=1';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement INTO l_out USING emp_rec.salary;
```